# Find regex and replace after some processing

Tags: python, regex

I know that in Python you can find and replace with

```
 re.sub('(b)','\\1BB','abc')
```

But, how would you proceed, if you wanted more processing, like you get a single digit number and you add x to it?

I'd have not problem doing it with a function and slicing and pasting the original string into a new one, with the regex matching pattern changed, but what is the simplest way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

You can call a function rather than a simple replacement string in [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> re.sub('(\d+)',
...     lambda x: ' {}+3={} '.format(x.group(1),int(x.group(1))+3),
...     'a12c')
'a 12+3=15 c'
```

Or,

```
def r(m):
    return ' {}+{}={} '.format(m.group(1),m.group(2),
                           int(m.group(1))+int(m.group(2)))

>>> print re.sub('(\d)(\d)',r,'a12c')
'a 1+2=3 c'
```